# Test Class - Testing Updates

Tags: apex, unit-test, commerce-cloud

I had to add a couple of updates to my class and now I'm only at 69% code coverage. How do you write tests when you are simply doing an update? I feel like I'm overthinking it, but then maybe not because of the API call.

Here is my class:

```java
public class OrderSummaryManager {

    @future (callout=true)
    public static void capturePayment(Id orderSummaryId){
        System.debug('OrderSummaryManager');
        OrderSummary orderSummary = [SELECT
              Id,
              ( SELECT Id FROM OrderPaymentSummaries WHERE AuthorizationAmount > 0 AND CapturedAmount = 0 ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC )
               FROM OrderSummary
               WHERE Id = :orderSummaryId
        ];
        if(orderSummary.OrderPaymentSummaries != null && orderSummary.OrderPaymentSummaries.size() > 0){
            OrderPaymentSummary ops = orderSummary.OrderPaymentSummaries.get(0);

            ops = [SELECT
              Id,
              ( SELECT Id, AccountId, Amount FROM PaymentAuthorizations WHERE Status = 'Processed' AND Amount > 0 AND Balance > 0 ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC )
               FROM OrderPaymentSummary
               WHERE Id = :ops.Id];
            System.debug('OrderSummaryManager - ops: ' + ops);
            if(ops.PaymentAuthorizations != null && ops.PaymentAuthorizations.size() > 0){
                PaymentAuthorization pa = ops.PaymentAuthorizations.get(0);

                ConnectApi.CaptureRequest captureRequest = new ConnectApi.CaptureRequest();

                captureRequest.accountId = pa.AccountId;
                captureRequest.amount = pa.Amount;
                captureRequest.comments = 'Capture ' + pa.Amount + '$';
                System.debug('OrderSummaryManager - captureRequest: ' + captureRequest);
                try{
                    ConnectApi.CaptureResponse response = ConnectApi.Payments.capture(captureRequest, pa.Id);
                    System.debug('OrderSummaryManager - response: ' + response);

                    // Assuming success, proceed with updating the Payment record
                    String paymentId = response.payment.Id;
                    System.debug('Payment ID: ' + paymentId);

                    // Update the Payment record with OrderPaymentSummaryId
                    Payment paymentToUpdate = new Payment(Id = paymentId);
                    paymentToUpdate.OrderPaymentSummaryId = ops.Id;

                    // Perform the update
                    update paymentToUpdate;          

                    System.debug('Payment record updated with OrderPaymentSummaryId');

                    // Update the Order Summary record with the captured payment Id
                    OrderSummary summaryToUpdate = new OrderSummary(Id = orderSummaryId);
                    summaryToUpdate.Captured_Payment__c = paymentId;

                    // Perform the update
                    update summaryToUpdate;

                    System.debug('Order Summary record updated with Captured_Payment__c');
                } catch(Exception e){
                    System.debug('Error: ' + e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my test class:

```java
@IsTest
public class OrderSummaryManagerTest {
    
    @IsTest(SeeAllData=true)
    public static void capturePaymentTest(){
        PaymentAuthorization pa = new PaymentAuthorization(
            Amount = 10,
            Status = 'Processed',
            ProcessingMode = 'External'
        );
        
        insert pa;
        
        Account acc = TestDataFactory.createAccount('smith');
        Contact con = TestDataFactory.createContact('smith', acc.Id);
        Product2 product = TestDataFactory.createProduct('product1');
        PriceBookEntry pbentry = TestDataFactory.createStandardPricebookEntry(product.Id, 1);
        Order order = TestDataFactory.createOrder(acc.Id, con.Id);
        OrderDeliveryMethod odm = TestDataFactory.createOrderDeliveryMethod('odm1', product.Id);
        OrderDeliveryGroup odg = TestDataFactory.createOrderDeliveryGroup(order.Id, odm.Id);
        OrderItem orderItem = TestDataFactory.createOrderItem(order.Id, product.Id, 1, 1, pbentry.Id, odg.Id);
        
        order.Status = 'Activated';
        update order;
        
        ConnectApi.OrderSummaryInputRepresentation osir = new ConnectApi.OrderSummaryInputRepresentation();
        osir.orderId = order.Id;
        osir.orderLifeCycleType = 'UNMANAGED';
        ConnectApi.OrderSummaryOutputRepresentation osor = ConnectApi.OrderSummaryCreation.createOrderSummary(osir);
        
        ConnectApi.CreateOrderPaymentSummaryInputRepresentation copsir = new ConnectApi.CreateOrderPaymentSummaryInputRepresentation();
        copsir.orderSummaryId = osor.orderSummaryId;
        copsir.paymentAuthorizationId = pa.Id;
        ConnectApi.CreateOrderPaymentSummaryOutputRepresentation copsor = ConnectApi.OrderPaymentSummary.createOrderPaymentSummary(copsir);

        Test.startTest();
        
        update new OrderSummary(
            Id = osor.orderSummaryId,
            Status = 'Shipped'
        );
        
        OrderSummaryManager.capturePayment(osor.orderSummaryId);
        
        Test.stopTest();
        
        }
    }
```

Can I just perform updates to the capturePayment and then the Order Summary? Or do I have to create a mock response to the capture payment? Or is there another way I can boost coverage?